# Proof of least squares approximation formulas?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, proof-verification, least-squares

I'm trying to study from this pdf: http://math.mit.edu/~gs/linearalgebra/ila0403.pdf

I was just wondering if there were any established proofs for the following formulas:

---

$\hat{y} = Zw$, where $\hat{y}, w$ are column vectors and $Z$ is a data matrix that is $N * M + 1$

---

$l(w) = ||Zw - t||^2$, $t$ being a column vector and where $||v||^2 = \sum_{n}{v_{n}^2}$

---

While searching for answers, I came across this post: [Proof of least squares approximation lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675308/proof-of-least-squares-approximation-lemma)

Would it be fair to say that this proves the second formula? How is the first formula proven?

**Edit**: [Here is a screenshot of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftYj4.png)

Comment: The second formula is just the definition of a function $\ell(w)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two results are actually definitions. Imagine you have a dataset of the form $\{y_i,(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_M)_i\}_{i=1}^N$. That is, you have $N$ observations $y_i$ of a variable that depends on $M$ independent features ${\bf x}_i = (x_1,x_2\cdots,x_M)_i$. Imagine there exists $M+1$ numbers $(w_0,w_1,w_2,\cdots w_M)$ such that each observation can be explained as the linear combination of the features with these weights, that is

\begin{eqnarray}
y_1 &=& w_0 + w_1 x_{1,1} + \cdots w_Mx_{M,1} +\epsilon_1\\
y_2 &=& w_0 + w_1 x_{1,2} + \cdots w_Mx_{M,2} +\epsilon_2\\
&\vdots& \\
y_N &=& w_0 + w_1 x_{1,N} + \cdots w_Mx_{M,N} +\epsilon_N\\
\end{eqnarray}

which can be represented in matrix form as

$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_N 
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & x_{1,1} & \cdots & x_{M,1} \\
1 & x_{1,2} & \cdots & x_{M,2} \\
 &  & \vdots &  \\
1 & x_{1,N} & \cdots & x_{M,N} \\
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
w_0 \\ w_1 \\ \vdots \\ w_M 
\end{array}\right) + 
\left(\begin{array}{c}
\epsilon_1 \\ \vdots \\ \epsilon_N 
\end{array}\right)
$$

or equivalently

$$
{\bf y} = {\bf Z}{\bf w} + {\bf \epsilon} = \hat{\bf y} + {\bf \epsilon}
$$

with $\hat{\bf y}={\bf Z}{\bf w}$, with ${\bf W}\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times(M+1)}$, ${\bf y}, {\bf \epsilon}\in \mathbb{R}^N$ and ${\bf w} \in \mathbb{R}^{M+1}$.

As for the second part, the idea is to find find the weights ${\bf w}$ such that the prediction $\hat{\bf y}$ is as close as possible to the real observation ${\bf y}$. That is why you define the distance between these two vectors as

$$
l({\bf w}) = ||{\bf Z}{\bf w} - {\bf y}||^2
$$

and try to minimize it

Comment: Is there a proof for them or are they just established? I get the definitions but I was asked to prove them and don't know how aside from just stating the definitions in the book.

Comment: @AndrewRaleigh I guess the first part is the proof you're looking for. The second part is just a definition, but you can see why it makes sense, you need to minimize the distance between the prediction and the actual observation, that's what $l({\bf w})$ measures

Comment: @AndrewRaleigh If you were asked to prove them, the assignment doesn't seem to make sense. Can you post a screenshot of the exact question from the assignment in your question?

Comment: @littleO I was also confused, I posted a screenshot of the question.